# websphere deployment through jenkins job

Tags: web-applications, jenkins, websphere

I have a webapp which runs fine on tomcat and websphere(through WAS console). But when I deploy through JENKINS, invoking the service gives below error on browser

Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet [com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet]: not a servlet class

Any help is appriciated !!

Answer (score 1):

During a deployment process on a WebSphere Application Server via Admin Console you have a step "Map web application to virtual host".

You need to generate binding resource for you application.